# Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0126' classic asp pls help

Tags: iis-6, asp-classic

our company have a a old classic asp application, we have no choice but to host it. I just moved it to another server. It was perfectly running fine in old server but in this new server it's continuously giving this error. I am running windows 2003 server with IIS 6. Why I am geting this error ? please help.

Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0126'

```
Include file not found

/application/unprocessed_application.asp, line 56

The include file '../../_fplclass/pdblib.inc' was not found.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change the code to use virtual path instead of file. Also make sure the application pool's user account has read access on that file.

`#include virtual=/_fpclass/pdblib.inc`

Answer (score 0):

The path to `pdblib.inc` is outside of the document root for your site based on the path `/application/unprocessed_application.asp`.  Make sure you have parent paths enabled on the new server, it is disabled by default in IIS6.

In IIS Manager,

1. Right-click your web site and click Properties
2. On the Home Directory tab click the Configuration button
3. Click Options and then make sure Enable Parent Paths is checked

EDIT:
You'll also get this error if you're using and `#include virtual=<path_to_file>` instead of `#include file=<path_to_file>`

Comment: I did it, still facing same problem

Comment: @sagarmatha see my edit